# Strange C++ header file function declaration

Tags: python, function, c++11, header, swig

I'm reading some source code that I'm trying to compile into python bindings, when I try `swig -c++ -python my_interface.i` I get a strange error.

I know the source code is written in C++11.

```cpp
// module.hpp
#pragma once

namespace module
{
    MODULE_API void getVersion (unsigned &params);
}
```

```
// my_interface.i
%module my_api
%{
#include "module.hpp"
%}

%include "module.hpp"
```

I don't have access to the source files, just the headers, and a shared library that we can call `modulelib.so`.

Does anybody know what the `MODULE_API` before the function return type means?

When I try to compile right now I get the error `module.hpp:29: Error: Syntax error in input(1)`
When I remove the `MODULE_API` the output moves to the next function declaration, because they all have this style of declaration, I'd delete them all, but I feel like that's going to break something.

Right now when I run `swig -v -wall -c++ -python my_interface.i` I recieve an error:

```
Language subdirectory: python
Search paths:
   ./
   ./swig_lib/python/
   /usr/share/swig3.0/python/
   ./swig_lib/
   /usr/share/swig3.0/
Preprocessing...
Starting language-specific parse...
module.hpp:6: Error: Syntax error in input(1).
```

Comment: I answered with regards to `MODULE_API`, but I can't really say what that compiler error is about, since you posted only a part of the error message. Could you come up with a [mcve], perhaps?

Comment: You definitely answered my question, I didn't know what any of it was, so I was trying to include as much information as possible.  I'll see if I can create an example

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept the answer, since you did actually answer the question I asked, thank you, but if you would like to continue to help, I'd definitely appreciate it.

Comment: I think you would be best served if you posted that as a new question, to be honest.

Comment: That's okay, as soon as I defined `MODULE_API` the error was solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common pattern to handle symbol visibility. Windows, for example, requires you to define functions with `__declspec(dllexport)` when *compiling* a library (so the linker knows to make the corresponding symbols externally visible), and `__declspec(dllimport)` when *using/linking* a library (so the linker knows that those symbols are to be imported from a DLL).

To avoid having to have two different headers (one for compiling, one for using the library), conditional defines are used:

```
#ifdef WIN32

  #ifdef MODULE_EXPORTS
    #define MODULE_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
    #define MODULE_API __declspec(dllimport)
  #endif

#else
  #define MODULE_API
#endif
```

This is merely an example. It does not *have* to be `MODULE_API` at all. Some projects use GCC's `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` and `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))`, but Windows is where this scheme originated, as Windows' *default* is to *hide* symbols.

Comment: They must have put this in because they compiled it on a Windows machine, since I'm using linux all I had to do was add `#define MODULE_API` at the top of the file and then it compiles as it should!